# Taking in Parameters in MIPS and returning $v0 and $v1

Tags: assembly, mips

for my upper level cs class we have to write a simple function called worddecrypt that does this:

Takes in 3 parameters, $a0, $a1, and $a2.
return $v0 = $a0 + $a1 + $a2
and return if ($v0 < $a1) $v1 = 1; else $v1 = 0

and this is my current code:

WordDecrypt:

```
    addi $t0, $a0, $a1
    addi $t0, $t0, $a2
    li $v0, $t0

    blt $v0, $a1, ELSE
    li $v1, 1
    ELSE:
    li $v1, 0
```

is there any faults in this code? I am super new to assembly with practically no experience. Any recommendations or fixes would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

The `li` pseudo-instruction is for loading immediates (e.g. `123` or `'A'`). If you want to move (copy) the value of one register to another, use `move`. Though in this case the use of `$t0` is unnecessary; you can just add directly to `$v0`:

```
addu $v0, $a0, $a1    # $v0 = $a0 + $a1
addu $v0, $v0, $a2    # $v0 = $a0 + $a1 + $a2
```

Note that `addi` is the wrong instruction to use, since it's meant for the case when the third operand is an immediate. You want `add` or `addu` (both do the same thing except `addu` doesn't trap on overflow).

Finally, `$v1 = ($v0 < $a1) ? 1 : 0` can be expressed in MIPS assembly as:

```
slt $v1, $v0, $a1   # slt = Set on Less Than
```

Or if you want an unsigned comparison, use `sltu`.